# Character table of $G=\langle (12),(34),(45)\rangle$.

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I consider the group $S_5$ and the subgroup $G=\langle (12),(34),(45)\rangle$. With help, I could find the conjugacy classes of $G$ and now I want to find the characters. Using that $\vert G \vert$ equals the sum of the squares of the $\chi(1)$'s I can fill in the first column of the table. Also, Since I have the trivial and the sign representation, I can fill the first and second row.
Now since (34) and (45) are in the same conjugacy class, I have $\lambda_i(34)=\lambda_i(45)$, so $\lambda_i((345))=\lambda_i((34)(45)) = \lambda_i(34)^2=1$ since because $(34)$ is of degree $2$. Now this is as far as I can go. What trick can I use to continue and how?
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
 & (1) & (34) & (345) & (12)  & (12)(34) & (12)(345)\\
 \text{Triv}& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 1 & 1\\
\text{Sign}&1&-1&1&-1&1&-1\\
\lambda_1&1&&1&&&\\
\lambda_2&1&&1&&&\\
\chi_1&2&&&&&\\
\chi_2&2&&&&&
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

The group has a quotient $S_3$ (acting on the points 3..5). Do you know the character table of $S_3$? Do you know how to lift a chjaracter from a quotient group to $G$? This gives you a character of degree 1 and one of degree 2. Tensoring with the sign then yields the full atble.

Comment: Definitely do this. Notice that your group is just $S_2\times S_3$ in a (thin) disguise. Write down the character table for that, and then map things over.

Comment: Thank you. I computed the character table of $S_2$ and $S_3$ and computed the kronecker product. It was very fast. But I'm curious : what does "The group has a quotient $S_3$ (acting on the points 3..5)" mean exactly?

Comment: @rol_saumon. The points 3,4,5 form one orbit for the group. When acting only on these three  points you get a homomorphism $G\to S_3$ that is onto.

Comment: Oh, I see. But then you take the quotient of $G$ by this orbite?